# Change tabs from within webview

Tags: javascript, webview, titanium, appcelerator

I've setup some webviews & with tabs in Appcelerator Titanium, but wondered:

**How can I change tabs from within the webview html?**

ie. I've split my app into 4 html pages (across 4 tabs). I have links in the html webviews which I would like to fire an event to switch tabs.

My tab items are setup as so in app.js:

```
var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow();
var tab1 = Titanium.UI.createTab({
    icon:'images/tabs/card1.png',
    title:'Card 1',
    window:win1
});

var webview1 = Titanium.UI.createWebView({url: 'index.html'});

win1.add(webview1);
win1.hideNavBar();
```

So in this example, i have an **a href** in index.html, which when clicked, i'd like to switch the app to the 3rd tab (which has a different webview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fire and event in the HTML file and listen for it in your application

[Ti.App.fireEvent Documentation Link](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.API.fireEvent-method.html)

Code in HTML file

```
<a href="/" onclick='Ti.App.fireEvent("wvClick",{new_tab:"tab_identifier"}); return    
           false;'>Switch Tab</a>
```

Code in js file

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('wvClick', function(data) 
{ 
Titanium.API.info("--> " + data.new_tab);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd done something similar which seemed to work, but would love to try this method out.  http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/75531/change-tabs-from-within-webview#answer